# How do you make X11 display over ssh connections faster?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn, netbeans, x11-forwarding

I have installed netbeans on a remote Solaris machine. When I try to access it over a VPN, the UI is rendered really slowly. I use ssh command with -X option on my local system to connect to the remote machine. My local system runs Ubuntu 12.04. One solution is to use

```
ssh -XC4c arcfour,blowfish-cbc username@host
```

However I found that even this wouldn't solve the problem fully. UI is still rendered slowly. Please suggest a solution so that UI experience is seemless.

Answer (score 4):

Try [xpra](http://xpra.org/) instead of `ssh -X`. It uses a somewhat customized protocol with many performance enhancements, and is able to detach/reattach remote programs.

Alternatively, [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/).

Comment: The remote server I am using is a Solaris machine. Is xpra available for Solaris as well?

Comment: There are builds for Solaris somewhere for sure, but install from source is probably just as easy: "./setup.py install"